# Nestjs can't start in docker because of /dist folder

Tags: javascript, docker, nestjs

I have nestjs & webpack & mongo (prisma) application running in docker, was able to get prod application docker config, webpack and nest builds created correctly (before I had hard times with this too, and only docker daemon reinstall helped to solve problems with prisma client generation, though I was searching for the issue in my configs).

Given separate docker containers for webpack and nest. Webpack dev server runs and writes his files to /public folder but Nest fails to write to its /dist for some reason with following error:

`nestjs start Error EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/dist'`

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
name: bookmeon

# For connection urls to the following instances, see
# https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/main/TESTING.md#environment-variables
services:
  # Replica Set (required for Prisma Client)
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/mongo.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '27018:27018'
#  app:
#    container_name: app
#    build:
#      dockerfile: ./docker/app.Dockerfile
#      args:
#        - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
#        - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
#        - AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
#        - AUTH0_DOMAIN=${AUTH0_DOMAIN}
#        - AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=${AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET}
#        - CLOUDINARY_BUCKET=${CLOUDINARY_BUCKET}
#        - CLOUDINARY_URL=${CLOUDINARY_URL}
#        - REDIS_URL=${REDIS_URL}
#        - ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID=${ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID}
#        - ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN=${ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN}
#        - ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER=${ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER}
#    env_file:
#      - .env
#    ports:
#      - '1337:1337'
#    depends_on:
#      - mongo
  nest:
    container_name: nest
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/nest.Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
        - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
        - AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
        - AUTH0_DOMAIN=${AUTH0_DOMAIN}
        - AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=${AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET}
        - CLOUDINARY_BUCKET=${CLOUDINARY_BUCKET}
        - CLOUDINARY_URL=${CLOUDINARY_URL}
        - REDIS_URL=${REDIS_URL}
        - ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID=${ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID}
        - ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN=${ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN}
        - ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER=${ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER}
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - .:/my
      - /my/node_modules
      - /my/dist
  webpack:
    container_name: webpack
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/webpack.Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
        - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
        - AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
        - AUTH0_DOMAIN=${AUTH0_DOMAIN}
        - AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=${AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET}
        - CLOUDINARY_BUCKET=${CLOUDINARY_BUCKET}
        - CLOUDINARY_URL=${CLOUDINARY_URL}
        - REDIS_URL=${REDIS_URL}
        - ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID=${ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID}
        - ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN=${ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN}
        - ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER=${ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER}
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '1338:1338'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - .:/my
      - /my/node_modules
      - /my/public
```

webpack.dockerfile:

```sh
###################
# base
###################
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18 As base
RUN apk add openssl1.1-compat
RUN apk add musl

RUN npm i -g pnpm

###################
# deps install
###################

FROM base As deps

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node ./package.json ./package.json

RUN pnpm i

###################
# build
###################

FROM base As build

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps ./my/. .
COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps ./my/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node ./aps ./aps
COPY --chown=node:node ./package.json ./package.json
COPY --chown=node:node ./webpack.js ./webpack.js

RUN mkdir ./public
RUN chown -R node:node ./public
RUN chmod 777 ./public

ARG NODE_ENV
ARG DATABASE_URL
ARG AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
ARG AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET
ARG AUTH0_DOMAIN
ARG CLOUDINARY_BUCKET
ARG CLOUDINARY_URL
ARG REDIS_URL
ARG ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID
ARG ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN
ARG ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER

USER node

ENTRYPOINT ["pnpm", "webpack"]
```

nest.dockerfile:

```sh
###################
# base
###################
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18 As base
RUN apk add openssl1.1-compat
RUN apk add musl

RUN npm i -g pnpm

###################
# deps install
###################

FROM base As deps

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node ./package.json ./package.json

RUN pnpm i

###################
# build
###################

FROM base As build

WORKDIR /my

COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps ./my/. .
COPY --chown=node:node --from=deps ./my/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node ./prisma ./prisma
COPY --chown=node:node ./tsconfig* .
COPY --chown=node:node ./src ./src
COPY --chown=node:node ./package.json ./package.json

RUN mkdir ./dist
RUN chown -R node:node ./dist
RUN chmod 777 ./dist

RUN pnpm exec prisma generate
RUN pnpm build

ARG NODE_ENV
ARG DATABASE_URL
ARG AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
ARG AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET
ARG AUTH0_DOMAIN
ARG CLOUDINARY_BUCKET
ARG CLOUDINARY_URL
ARG REDIS_URL
ARG ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_ID
ARG ROCKETSMS_ACCOUNT_TOKEN
ARG ROCKETSMS_PHONE_NUMBER

USER node

ENTRYPOINT ["pnpm", "start"]
```

Comment: It looks like nothing from either image is getting used; your `volumes:` overwrite pretty much all of the image contents with possible-different content from a host directory or from anonymous volumes.  Does deleting the `volumes:` blocks help?  (The MongoDB container _should_ have `volumes:`, the application containers should not.)

Comment: I have tried to remove top level volumes section completely (even with db), called docker-compose down -v as well, then docker-compose build --no-cache. It doesn't help. Though I didn't remove application volume mapping to `.:/my`. As I understand if I remove it, then webpack dev server and nestjs server will not react to file changes. I will try to remove aps volumes completely anyway ant let you know soon.

Comment: The volume mapping `.:/my` is the big one that will overwrite literally everything in the image, and I'd consider that an important one to remove.  Yes, it means a dev server in an isolated container won't respond to host file changes; you can use a host Node environment without Docker at all, and use Docker for integration testing and deployment.

Comment: Yep, My idea was just have option for anyone to start faster with local development, or local presentation. Run one docker task instead of using readme and running 3 tasks. (dockerized mongo, as it needs to run replicas, webpack and nestjs )

Thanks, Your suggestion worked. It seems that it's crazy idea to map `./:` because it creates that conflicts on /dist folder, but interesting that ./public folder writes has no such issue, though config is the same (and dockerized webpack writes to this folder). I tried to close everything that might use /dist folder, so not sure what blocked it

Comment: And to run webpack/nest locally in development mode, we could map just FE files and BE files, not whole root folder. Will try and let you know!

Comment: But This kid of issue looks similar to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/783

I also have this /dist folder not accessible by nestjs typescript @DavidMaze

Comment: Yeah something with typescript, and what's interesting `RUN pnpm build` works fine (though it compiles TS to JS as well) but `ENVIRONMENT pnpm start` fails with `error TS5033: Could not write file '/my/dist/` @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

So, i My case the problem arised because of user which runs nest at the end.
I don't know how to configure other user to run nest application w/o errors about files permissions, so I just removed `#USER node` and

```js
#RUN mkdir ./dist
#RUN chown -R node:node ./dist
#RUN chmod 777 ./dist
```

And it works.

Looks like when node user tries to run already compiled nest application there is no isssues, but when you try to start nest application and compile it as node user it fails (with typescript issue: error TS5033: Could not write file '/my/dist/ )

So, if you have this kind of trouble, configure user properly or just use default (looks like it's root) anyway as you use it locally most likely there will be no security issues.